# Why Eloquent HasMany return an empty collection?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hi why i get an empty collection when i use $user->posts as property. However i do a get collection when i use $user->posts() as function.

```
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }

    public function index(User $user){
        dd($user->posts);
         return view('home', compact('user'));
    }

    @foreach($user->posts as $post)
        <p>$post->title</p>
        <p>$post->body</p>
    @endforeach
```

```
result
Collection {#1102 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method (`user`) should be in your `post` model.

The second method (`posts`) should be in your `user` model.

Check your database and see if the posts table has a column named `user_id`.

Check your database and see if the `user_id` column has a valid value (according to the `users` table.

Also make sure your route has `{user}` in it. Something like this:

```
Route::get('home/{user}', 'Cotroller@method')
```

Comment: I have checked everything is correct still not getting desired result.

Comment: Auth::user()->posts worked but why not $user->posts ?

Answer (score 0):

User model:

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Post model:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

And make sure you have `user_id` column on your `post` table